# Is it harmful that my rabbit eats bugs?

Tags: health, diet, rabbits, safety, eating

My rabbit is now eating bugs such as crickets and those things. She hasn't shown any signs of health problems while she ate them, but I'm not sure if they're healthy at all for her. The crickets are just in our normal backyard, and every time she runs around the yard, she eats bugs - especially crickets. She apparently wants to eat with her normal feeding. They do live in my backyard and she has eaten some of them inside her burrow to "defend" her burrow. Would bugs harm her in any way?

Comment: The crickets, per se, are harmless and may be a decent additional source of nutrition. My concerns would be whether they've picked up insecticides from your neighbor's garden, and whether there are any parasites which the crickets might be a vector for.

Comment: @keshlam not that i know of but she hasn't shown anything for 8 months.

Answer (score 2):

No, she's safe to eat bugs if she wishes. The only concern would be if the bugs have insecticides on them but as you commented above chances seem slim.

Insects are not a common vector to transmit intestinal parasites to rabbits.